# How to show error in a field without text (Empty)

Tags: python

I have a small problem with the empty field (without text) in the api in the description field, I would like that when searching for a kind of weapon it appears that it does not have a description

This is the code I'm using:

```
import json
import requests

args = input("Escribe: ")
rarity = input("rareza: ")





response = requests.get("https://jose89fcb.es/apifortnite/weapons.php")
data = response.json()



for api in data['weapons']:
    if args == api["name"].strip():
     if rarity == api["rarity"]:
        
        print(f'Desc: {api["description"]}')
```

In this case, the empty field is in the description and I would like an error "No description" to appear.

Could someone help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check if it is empty:

```
import json
import requests

args = input("Escribe: ")
rarity = input("rareza: ")

response = requests.get("https://jose89fcb.es/apifortnite/weapons.php")
data = response.json()

for api in data['weapons']:
    if args == api["name"].strip():
     if rarity == api["rarity"]:
        description = api["description"]
        if description:
            print(f'Desc: {description}')
        else:
            print("No description")
```